# last working day of previous month with LocalDate

Tags: java, date, java-time, localdate

```
public static String getLastWorkingDayOfPreviousMonth() {

    LocalDate lastDayOfCurrentMonth = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    LocalDate lastWorkingDayOfMonth;

    switch (DayOfWeek.of(lastDayOfCurrentMonth.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK))) {
        case SATURDAY:
            lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1);
            break;
        case SUNDAY:
            lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(2);
            break;
        default:
            lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth;
    }

    return getFormattedDate(lastWorkingDayOfMonth);
}
```

The above gives last working day of the current month. How can I get the last working day of the `Previous` month adjusting the above?

Comment: `lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1);` ???  This would get you the last day of the previous month, not the last working day. Do you mean to use `minusDays(...)` instead?

Comment: As for the last working day of the previous month: once your code is fixed just feed `lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1)` to your switch statement, e.g. `switch (lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1).getDayOfWeek() )` (note the method `getDayOfWeek()` which shortens the statement and thus increases readability tremendously).

Comment: thanks - I see where it went wrong. I updated the `lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1);` to `lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusDays(1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, the simple approach is better than a clever approach:

```
LocalDate lastWorkingDayOfMonth = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1);
do {
    lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastWorkingDayOfMonth.minusDays(1);
} while (lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ||
         lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
```

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative is to use a `java.time.YearMonth` to get the previous month. Then you get the last day of this month and adjust to previous Friday if it's in a weekend:

```
LocalDate lastDayPreviousMonth = YearMonth
    // current year/month
    .now()
    // previous month
    .minusMonths(1)
    // last day of month
    .atEndOfMonth();
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = lastDayPreviousMonth.getDayOfWeek();
// check if it's weekend
if (dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
    // adjust to previous friday
    lastDayPreviousMonth = lastDayPreviousMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
}
```

Running this code today (October 2<sup>nd</sup> 2017), it gives `lastDayPreviousMonth` equals to `2017-09-29`.

---

**PS:** You're using `minusMonths` in `LocalDate` instances, which wont' always work like you want. Example, if I have a date in February 2017:

```
// Feb 15th 2017
LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 15);
// adjust to last day of month (2017-02-28)
d = d.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(d.minusMonths(1)); // 2017-01-28
```

The last day of February 2017 is 28<sup>th</sup>, and when calling `minusMonths(1)`, you get the same day (28<sup>th</sup>) at the previous month (January), which is not what you want (the last working day in January 2017 is 31<sup>st</sup>).

Using `YearMonth` avoids this, because this class handles just the month and year, ignoring the day (so the `minusMonths` doesn't suffer such effects). So you can easily go to the desired month, and then you can correctly get the last day using the `atEndOfMonth()` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your switch statement with the following code:

```
public static String getLastWorkingDayOfPreviousMonth() {

        LocalDate lastDayOfCurrentMonth = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        LocalDate lastWorkingDayOfMonth;
        switch (lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1).getDayOfWeek()) {
            case SATURDAY:
                lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1).minusDays(1); // Here assgining second last day from previous month.
                break;
            case SUNDAY:
                lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1).minusDays(2); // Here assgining third last day from previous month.
                break;
            default:
                lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1); // Here assgining last day from previous month.
        }

        return lastWorkingDayOfMonth.toString();
    }
```

Here, in this case I am calculating the last day of previous month (you can change the months before by changing the integer value in method `minusMonths()`'s parameter) with the weekends and in case of Weekends the Working day is changed accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()
         .withDayOfMonth( 1 ) 
         .with( 
             org.threeten.extra.Temporals.previousWorkingDay()
          )
```

## `previousWorkingDay`

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project provides [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementations for finding the [next](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDay--)/[previous](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#previousWorkingDay--) weekday (non-Saturday/Sunday).

The last day of the previous month may be the target, a weekday. So our strategy is to get the first day of *this* month, the look back to get first previous working day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ; 
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
LocalDate firstOfMonth = today.withDayOfMonth( 1 ) ;
LocalDate lastWorkingDayOfPreviousMonth = firstOfMonth.with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.previousWorkingDay() ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

More simple and easy way without looping.

```
public static String getLastWorkingDayOfPreviousMonth() {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    if (localDate.getDayOfWeek().getValue() > 5)
        localDate = localDate.minusDays(localDate.getDayOfWeek().getValue() - 5);
    return getFormattedDate(localDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace  `LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())`
in your code to `LocalDate.now().minusMonth(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())` to get the last day of the previous month and after that keep on with the same logic to find the last working day of the month.